# Blogger feed posts showing CORS Error on different site

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cors, blogger

With reference to [this answer of Google](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/97933), I tried to use the json version of my feeds by using the URL: `https://[blog address].blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json`. My blog is set to  public mode, but then also it is throwing CORS policy. And this is the code I used:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status === 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status, xhr.response);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
getJSON('https://[blog].blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json',
function(err, data) {
  if (err !== null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    alert('Your query count: ' + data.query.count);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: You cannot access that endpoint from a Javascript program running in a browser, because it does not support cross-origin requests (CORS). Perhaps you can make the request from your web server (the one that serves the HTML you shared).

Comment: Try [`alt=json-in-script`](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json?hl=en#json-in-script-output) instead.

Comment: I am trying this with a frontend site and `alt=json-in-script` does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`alt=json-in-script`](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json?hl=en#json-in-script-output) instead:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction({feed}) {
  alert('Your query count: ' + feed.entry.length);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://blog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&callback=myFunction"></script>
```